# Does ffplay has support for https with ssl client certificate

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a webserver streaming a video over hls (https).My webserver needs ssl client certificate to authenticate.How I can provide ssl client certificate to ffplay so that I can play the hls stream.I am getting a 400 - bad request error while trying to play https url.

Comment: Show the full command and log.

Comment: ffplay http://192.168.26.43/hls13/master.m3u8                                          
avplay version 0.8.17-4:0.8.17-0ubuntu0.12.04.2, Copyright (c) 2003-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Apr  1 2016 14:28:02 with gcc 4.6.3                            
Unable to open key file https://192.168.26.43/hls13/HryDsbza
http://192.168.26.43/hls13/master.m3u8: Invalid data found when processing input                          
The stream is encrypted and I want to share the keys over https with client ssl authentication.ffplay is failing to download key.

Comment: That's not the real ffplay. It's an outdated fork. Get it from https://ffmpeg.org/download.html and then run `ffplay -cert_file=<yourfile> tls://StreamingURL`

Comment: I am keeping master playlist and segments in http folder where as encryption keys in https folder. In that case the above command won't work.Can you tell me how to overcome that ?